# SQL SUM() different table different columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

Category Table

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM cats;
+------+-----------+
| c_id | c_name    |
+------+-----------+
|    1 | cats 1    |
|    2 | cats 2    |
|    3 | cats 3    |
+------+-----------+
```

Meta Table

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM meta;
+------+------+----------+-------------+-------+
| m_id | c_id | name     | description | costs |
+------+------+----------+-------------+-------+
|    1 |    1 | Abhijit1 | description | 100   |
|    2 |    1 | Abhijit2 | description | 200   |
|    3 |    2 | Abhijit3 | description | 500   |
|    4 |    3 | Abhijit4 | description | 800   |
+------+------+----------+-------------+-------+
```

meta and cats table common is c_id
meta table cats c_id(1) meta table have 2 (Abhijit1,Abhijit2) row with m_id(1,2)

Transaction Table

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM transactions;
+------+------+------------+--------+
| t_id | m_id | date       | amount |
+------+------+------------+--------+
|    1 |    1 | 2016-02-01 | 50     |
|    2 |    1 | 2016-02-06 | 50     |
|    3 |    3 | 2016-02-15 | 400    |
|    4 |    4 | 2016-02-19 | 150    |
+------+------+------------+--------+
```

transactions and meta table common is m_id
transactions for m_id 1 have 2 row t_id(1,2)
this table mainly for paid amount and date

I want to sum() for each category all costs (from meta table) and amount( from transaction table).

tables are connect with

```
cats.c_id
    |
    |-----> meta.c_id
    |-----> meta.m_id
                |-----> transactions.m_id
```

It's wrong. The Costs of cats id 1 is 300 but here I got 400

```
I Want Get Return From Query Like This:
+------+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| c_id | c_name    | SUM(m.costs) | SUM(t.amount) |
+------+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|    1 | cats 1    |          300 |           100 |
|    2 | cats 2    |          500 |           400 |
|    3 | cats 3    |          800 |           150 |
+------+-----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Here SUM(m.costs) are all Cost For a category and SUM(t.amount) are all paid for a category

Please help me or any better Idea for Table management.

Comment: And your current query is.... ?

Comment: Your question is confusing "The Costs of cats id 1 is 300 but here I got 400" cats id says 300 for m.costs and t.amount. Why do you say its 400? With the data provided shouldn't sum of t.amount be 100?

Comment: Shouldn't `SUM(t.amount)` for category 1 be 100 (50+50)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that you join `transactions` so as to get `SUM(t.amount)`. Hence, `costs` values are accounted for twice in case a single `meta` records is associated with two `transactions` record.

You can get around this problem using a correlated subquery to calculate `SUM(t.amount)`:

```sql
SELECT c.c_id, 
       c.c_name, 
       SUM(m.costs),
       (SELECT SUM(t.amount)
        FROM transactions AS t
        WHERE m.m_id = t.m_id)
FROM cats AS c
LEFT JOIN meta AS m ON c.c_id = m.c_id
GROUP BY c.c_id, c.c_name
```

**Output:**

```
c_id c_name  SUM(m.costs)   SUM(t.amount) 
-----------------------------------------
1    cats 1  300            100
2    cats 2  500            400
3    cats 3  800            150
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e4c36/1)

Comment: ***Thank You So So Much For Your Answer***

Comment: Can you sagest me that what the best way to learn mysql. php. javascript

Comment: any book tutorials. Please can you tell me how can i learn programming more deepth. Thanks again

Comment: @ABHIJIT The best way to learn programming is by doing, writing actual programs, building actual applications. You can also learn a lot here in SO. Check [this](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-jQuery-Missing-Manual-Manuals/dp/1491947071/ref=sr_1_8?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1455723963&sr=1-8&keywords=jquery)  book out for Javascript and JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT cats.c_id,
       cats.c_name,
       (SELECT SUM(m.cost) FROM meta WHERE cats.c_id = m.c_id) AS cost,
      (SELECT SUM(t.cost) FROM meta WHERE t.id = m.id) AS amount
WHERE c.c_id = 1
```